# Replace with SED multiple occurences at the same line

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I want to replace all slashes "/" between alphanumeric with backslash+slash "\/" apart from the last one on each string, e.g.

```
nocareNocare abc\/def/ghi/mno\/pq/r   abc\/def\/ghi/mno\/pq/r
```

should become:

```
nocareNocare abc\/def\/ghi\/mno\/pq/r   abc\/def\/ghi\/mno\/pq/r
```

I use:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)\([[:alnum:]]\)\/\([[:alnum:]]\)\(\S*\)\(\\\|\/\)/\1\2\\\/\3\4\//g'
```

Short explanation: match

> any string + alnum + / + any non-white + / or \

But it only replace one case, so I need to run it 3 times to replace all 3 occurences. Looks like the first time it matches all the way to :

```
>nocareNocare abc\/def/ghi/mno\/pq/r   abc\/def\/ghi/
```

instead of

```
>nocareNocare abc\/def/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `perl` command line solution based on the following `regEx`'s

`(?<!\\)`

not preceded by a backslash

`(?!\w+\s)`

not followed by word characters terminating in whitespace

```
perl -pe 's;(?<!\\)/(?!\w+\s);\\/;g' file
nocareNocare abc\/def\/ghi\/mno\/pq/r   abc\/def\/ghi\/mno\/pq/r
```

Comment: You cracked it! Thanks for your help from the start to the end! I also handles case that there an underscore before the slash, which is great.

Comment: @user2405602: Cheers! Happy to help!

Answer (score 3):

```
sed -e :a -e 's|\([a-z0-9]\)/\([a-z0-9][^ ]*[a-z0-9]/[a-z0-9]\)|\1\\/\2|;ta' filename
```

Loosely translated, this says "replace a lone slash followed by some other stuff in the string, followed by another lone slash, with backslash-slash and that same stuff (and the second slash). And after making such a replacement, start over again."

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
sed -E 's:([^\])/:\1\\/:g;s:\\/([^\]*( |$)):/\1:g' file
```

Two `s` command here:

- `s:([^\])/:\1\\/:g` replace all `/` not preceded by a `\` with `\/`
- `s:\\/([^\]*( |$)):/\1:g` replace last `\/` before space or end of line with `/`

Comment: Thanks, but this is doesn't do it, because the 2nd step you describe also replaces some "\/" that were there in the initial version, and that I do not want.